# при попытке скомпилировать проект получаю ошибку: Exception: Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, augmented-reality

проект не мой, и изначально он делался под IOS, мне же нужно под андроид... Я везде поменял на Android, удалил все что связано с IOS, при попытке скомпилировать проект получаю это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

спасибо Вам заранее.

Comment: Это не С# исключение, это C++.

Comment: то есть в проекте есть скрипт написанный на языке C++?